# Merging large counter instances

Tags: python-3.x, memory, memory-management, counter, large-files

I wrote very simple script to merge counts of keys which are stored as a set of text files. All of them follow the format:

```
multi word key1 count1
multi word key2 count2
...
```

Each file can contain a few million lines, resulting in files of size between 0.1GB to 2GB. So the files are relatively large and many of them (about 100) grouped in different folders and subfolders. An easy approach  to merge them are these two functions:

```
 from collections import Counter

 def merge(path_to_maindir):
     merged = Counter()
     for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path_to_maindir):
         for f in files:
             file = os.path.join(root, f)
             merged += load_txt_to_Counter(file)
     return merged

 def load_txt_to_Counter(path)
     counts = Counter()
     with open(path, 'r' , encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as file:
         for line in file:
             entry = line.rstrip().rsplit(maxsplit=1) 
             counts[entry[0]] += int(entry[1])
     return counts
```

I ran this script with 10 files (as described above). Together the files are 5GB. I'm running this script on a windows 7, Intel i7, 64 Bit machine with 16GB memory and python 3.4. Firstly, the script runs normal with a CPU usage of about 40%, the memory usage climbs steadily. At some point the memory is full. So the 5GB of text data take more than three times as much memory as a Counter instance with the same data? I didn't expect that. How? Also once the memory is full the CPU usage drops to 0%. So it's doing swapping, but CPU load stays on 0%. Every 30 minutes there might be a 'peak' to 12%? The memory stays pretty much full all the time.

Now I know I could load parts of each file, create a smaller counter instance and add them incrementally or completely ignore this approach import the files into a proper database and do the merging within a database. This would give me a practical solution (which I did), but my question is more aiming for an educational purpose: I would like to now why this fairly simple script behaves like it does? I'm new to python and I probably just made a stupid beginner mistake.

Regards
Sevrino

*edit: fixing typos*

Comment: How many distinct entries are in these files and how long (on average) are the multi word keys?

Comment: Millions distinct entries, usually 4 words, max 5. Oh something that I should have mentioned I know that `counter + counter` creates a new counter instance. I know it's slow and I'm currently using the `update` function instead. For the question is more why the CPU load is behaving like it is.